# Using Angular in a SPA of Extjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs, extjs4, single-page-application

I have a SPA website that works with Extjs.

What i try to implement is that on clicking a menu item, an html page written in angular should be loaded. I wrote an html file which contains my angular screen and put it in a Extjs panel ([using this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/LoadyourhtmlfiletoaExtPanel.htm)). Although the html elements are shown (my button actually), the angular part (the scripts) does not work.

Ps: angular and all other necessary modules are already loaded.

HTML Part:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <button id="button_add" class="btn" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    <span> {{n}} </span>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
            ]);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.n = 0;

                $scope.add = function () {
                    $scope.n = $scope.n + 1;
                };
            }
        ]);
    </script>
</div>
```

Extjs Part:

```
var test = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title : 'Example 1',
            width : 250,
            height : 250,
            frame : true,
            autoLoad : {
                url : './test.html'
            }
        });
```

And the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: try this:    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','uiGridConstants','uiGridConstants', '$http', function ($scope, uiGridConstants, $http) .  Is there any console error???

Comment: Sorry! When i tried to simplify my code, i had forget to delete the arguments! But anywayn i see no any error in my console even if there are problems with my syntax.

Comment: Try to include your  <script>
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [
            ]);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.n = 0;

                $scope.add = function () {
                    $scope.n = $scope.n + 1;
                };
            }
        ]);
    </script>  in head tag

Comment: I have tried it now, but the result is unfortunately the same

Comment: And you have also included the angular.js file? Just confirming

Comment: Yes, it is also included.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-loadScript

Comment: @Seram I have added the angular.min.js before my panel. It gives a "success", thus it is loaded. But still, my extern html file does not use it. (i've also tried to execute my html using html: <code>...", but the result is the same)

Comment: it seems that its about angular. Angular is working in <body> but in a new loaded page, angular has been not detected automatically. I should load angular each time when the page is loaded.